# Why apt-get purge doesn't clear Chromium .config and .cache

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-14.04, chromium

I have installed Chrome (chromium) in the Ubuntu environment, using either apt-get install, Ubuntu Software Center or via regular apt-get upgrade (I have also installed chrome from the official site https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/) as 32.deb file.

They are visible via Ubuntu Software Center and can be uninstalled and reinstalled this way.

```
~$ sudo apt-get purge chrome
Reading package list... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package chrome


~$ whereis chrome

   chrome:

~$ sudo apt-get purge chromium
Reading package list... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Package 'chromium' is not installed, so not removed
```

However that does not provide a clear representation of the status of other accompanied settings such as ".config", ".cache"etc. that may need to be cleared due to virus infection or other reasons.

Would that be incoherent with OS file structure and is there is a different installation method that bind these browsers in more coherency with OS in use.

```
uname -a:

3.16.0-48-generic #64~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 20 23:03:49 UTC 2015 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux
```

Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85
[image: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/]

[[image]]

Comment: These files are not *installed* by the package. Why would it remove them? `apt-get` never removes private configuration. There might be many users, after all.

Comment: ~$ apt-cache policy chrome     N: Unable to locate package chrome

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, but there's not a `chrome` package nor there is a `chromium` package by default; when you use the Ubuntu Software Center you make a search and it returns there's a `chromium` program, but in order to install it, you need to install the `chromium-browser` package (which the Ubuntu Software Center does for you).

You can also make searches in the command line, by using the `apt-cache search` command. For instance:

```
# apt-cache search chromium
[...]
chromium-browser - Chromium web browser, open-source version of Chrome
chromium-browser-l10n - chromium-browser language packages
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg - Free ffmpeg codecs for the Chromium Browser
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra - Extra ffmpeg codecs for the Chromium Browser
```

In order to see which source has the package, you can use `apt-cache policy` as well:

```
# apt-cache policy chromium-browser
chromium-browser:
  Installed: 44.0.2403.89-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1095
  Candidate: 44.0.2403.89-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1095
  Version table:
 *** 44.0.2403.89-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1095 0
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     34.0.1847.116-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: The original title of my question was "What makes Chrome invisible to apt-get" where as you see was not located. Would that be an installation error--if so which installation method will avoid this. The gentleman that edited the question also has a valid point when the OS apt-get purge is not sufficient and rm need to be used.